# log parser 2.2 query, Text parsing and validating

Tags: c#, parsing, text-parsing, logparser

There is a simple text file that have to be parse by using log parser.
Just I started using log parser but not understanding What is its parsing limit. I mean Can i do such thing by using logparser

TextLine to parse:

```
1022303Name      WXP3
```

This I have to parse like

First digit `1` is row name
Next three digit `022` is errorNumber
next three digit `303` is UserID
next ten char `Name` is UserName
next 4 char `WXP3` is SystemName

I am not able to understand can we do this query from log parser or not...
If yes then give any sample query.

**ANY OTHER TOOL TO PERFORM THIS IS MOST WELCOMED**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the SUBSTR function.

```
logparser -i:textline "select substr(text, 0, 1) AS RowName, substr(text, 1, 3) AS ErrorNumber, substr(text, 4, 3) AS UserId, substr(text, 7, 10) AS UserName, substr(text, 17, 4) AS SystemName from temp.txt
```

This assumes the lengths are really set to a particular size.

temp.txt text used above:

```
1022303Name1     WXP3
1022303Name 2    WXP4
1022303Name 3    WXP5
1022303Name 4    WXP6
1022303Name 5    WXP7
1022303Name 6    WXP8
1022303Name 7    WXP9
1022303Name 8    WXPa
```

Since it's been linked to before, I'll also point you to [Log Parser Plus](http://logparserplus.com/), which I 'run,' and may be of some help with other log parser functions.

Comment: Just in case ... SUBSTR(text-to-search, start-position, characters-to-parse) where start-position is 0-based.

Comment: Thanx... I think it will solve my problem. Just one more question, Can we validate the data like numeric type or text type?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could potentially use ROUND or TO_INT (you'd have to test to see what it'll do to a non-numeric string) ... However, I would expect that you'd have accept the log file itself is valid (for Log Parser). If the application that creates those logs doesn't output valid log files, then that's a much bigger issue.

Comment: Yup!! correct, can u suggest any tutorial URL... I am getting interest in log parser

Comment: Official forums are at http://forums.iis.net/default.aspx?GroupID=51 and there's the book "Microsoft Log Parser Toolkit" (I'd consider it more of a reference than a tutorial). Outside of that ... not really. There's a lot of queries floating around out there; I already mentioned my site in the answer, and Server Fault and Stack Overflow have a ton of answers with good queries. If you find any, do let me know!

Comment: And there's also a couple different visual-based UIs for Log Parser as well. http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/ seems to be the most referenced version. I haven't been able to find the other one, so it may have been discontinued.

Comment: Thanx James... Today was a worthy day, I learn about new tool and tons for you for help

Comment: That's *great* to hear. Glad I could be of help :D

Comment: Very Helpful, I was able to use it with "NCSALOG"s to group by the request field and trim the the stuff that varied from the end of the request string. Thanks!